# How do I compute the absolute value of a vector in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, absolute-value

How do I compute the absolute value of a vector in Eigen? Since the obvious way

```
Eigen::VectorXf v(-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0);
v.abs(); // Compute abs value.
```

does not work.

Comment: Try `cout << v.abs() << endl` :)

Comment: Have you tried `v = v.cwiseAbs();`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For Eigen 3.2.1 using `p.abs();` in the same way as you would use `p.normalize` results in a compiler error along the lines of

> error: no member named 'abs' in 'Eigen::Matrix' p.abs();
>       ~ ^

so a vector in Eigen is nothing but a Matrix type. To compute the absolute values of a matrix in Eigen one can use `p.cwiseAbs()` or array conversion `p.array().abs();`. Both these absolute functions returns a value rather than modifying the variable itself.

So a correct way of doing it would be to do

```
p = p.cwiseAbs();
```

or

```
p = p.array().abs();
```